# How do I access data in MUI table in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, json, material-ui

So I'm getting some data from a server which returns a json, i want to loop through this data and display some information received from the server. That works but the issue is I have Popover which contains an items with a on click event, so that actions can be performed on each table row but the problem is, anytime I try to access an item via the onclick event, it always gets the id for the last item. Below is my code:

```
<Table size="small">
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell>Product</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Category</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Code</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Rate</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Color</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
      <TableBody>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <TableRow key={product.id}>
            <TableCell>{product.category}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{product.code}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{product.rate}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>{product.color}</TableCell>
            <TableCell>
              <Button
                aria-describedby={id} variant="contained" onClick={handleClick} size="small"
                endIcon={<KeyboardArrowDownIcon />} sx={{ mt: 1, mb: 1, backgroundColor: "#0046AF", width: 120, color: "#fff" }}>
                Action
              </Button>
              <Popover
                id={id} open={openPopup} anchorEl={anchorEl}
                onClose={handleClose} anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'bottom', horizontal: 'left', }} sx={{ boxShadow: 'none' }}>
                <List className="invpopover">
                  <ListItem>
                    <Button variant="text" onClick={() => handleOpenInternal(product.id)} style={{ color: "#000", textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                      <ListItemText primary="Close internally" />
                    </Button>
                  </ListItem>
                  <ListItem>
                    <Button variant="text" onClick={() => showRemoveProductModal(product.id)} style={{ color: "#000", textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                      <ListItemText primary="Remove" />
                    </Button>
                  </ListItem>
                </List>
              </Popover>
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        ))}
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
```

Below is the business logic:

```
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const [openInternal, setOpenInternal] = React.useState(false);
  const [removeProductModal, setRemoveProductModal] = React.useState(false);

  const [products, setProducts] = React.useState([]);

  const [productId, setProductId] = React.useState(-1);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const openPopup = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = openPopup ? 'simple-popover' : undefined;

  const handleOpenInternal = (productId) => {
    setOpenInternal(true);
    setProductId(productId);
    console.log(productId); // This always prints the id of the last record
  };

  const showRemoveProductModal = (productId) => {
    setProductId(productId);
    setRemoveProductModal(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const getAllProducts = async () => {
    const productList = await InventoryManagementRepository.getAllProducts();
    setProducts(productList); // returns 25 records.
  };
```

My question is how do i make sure I get the ID of the row item i click on and not the last one?

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood the problem correctly. If so, in fact the issue appears because you are using the same anchorEl state over each and every Popover element. If you want to iterate over an array of data (or object), mapping each to a Popover, you want their anchoring to be unique. If you are using the same anchorEl for each of them, the effect is probably a re-render of each already created element over and over until every single one of them is rendered.

In ReactJS, you can create either an array or an object state to hold this data
`const [anchorEls, setAnchorEls] = useState(data.map((x) => null));` and so for each open / close action you want to update the current state array / object on the needed index.

EDIT:

The solution is pretty straight forward. You need to creat a state array in order to keep all your anchor elements and modify each of them considering the index of each product (a.k.a. data) in your list.

Here is a quick demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-bouman-lyfuor?file=/src/App.js

Comment: you certainly understood the problem. But I don't actually understand the solution you are proposing. If you could update the code in your answer to be more elaborate that will be helpful. Thanks.